# ¿Como parsear una matriz String a Integer o int? (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, matrices, parsear, cast

```
    String [][] matriz = {{"1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"}};
```

Tengo la siguiente matriz String, hay alguna forma en que se pudiera parsear a Integer o Int? de antemano gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Para esta y proxímas oportunidades que compartas tus preguntas. Recuerda incluir el código que hayas intentado usar para resolver tu problema. Traer preguntas sin código suena mucho a "resuélvanlo" y suena a poco interés por resolverlo :)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que estas buscando es  `Integer.parseInt(myString)` [Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) aplicamos el parser en un bucle (como si lo fueras a imprimir) te dejo un ejemplo aplicado. También puedes hacer lo mismo pero con un casteo (pero te puede dar errores en tiempo de ejecución) [Documentación Cast](https://www.discoduroderoer.es/casting-en-java/)

```
    String [][] matriz = {{"1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"}};
    int[][] matrizInt= new int[matriz.length][matriz[0].length];
    for (int i = 0;matriz.length > i ;i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0;matriz[i].length > j;j++) {
            matrizInt[i][j] =  Integer.parseInt(matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes pasar de la matriz original de `String`s a matriz de `int`s usando Streams de Java 8:

```
String [][] matriz = {{"1","2","3"},{"4","5","6"},{"7","8","9"}};
int[][] intMatriz = Arrays.stream(matriz)
        .map(stringArray ->
                Arrays.stream(stringArray)
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray()
        )
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convertir un array bidimensional String a un array bidimensional tipo Int.**

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma, primeramente declarando un array entero para almacenar los datos con la misma dimensión de tu array String.

```
    String[][] matriz = {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}, {"7", "8", "9"}};
    int[][] matrizInt = new int[3][3];

    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        String cells[] = matriz[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            matrizInt[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(cells[j]);
        }
    }
```

Puedes imprimir el Array resultante para comprobar el contenido del array resultante:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrizInt));
```

para obtener como salida:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Otra forma es como lo indica [Glen Sandoval](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383051/95):

```
    String[][] matriz = {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5", "6"}, {"7", "8", "9"}};

    int[][] matrizInt = Arrays.stream(matriz)
    .map(stringArray -> Arrays.stream(stringArray)
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .toArray()
    )
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

de esta forma obtendrías el mismo resultado